# What is the jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 - Position-Fixed Method

Tags: ios, mobile, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 Final was just released and promises:

> "True fixed toolbars: Lightweight, CSS-based & broadly compatible"

What is the *specific* fix they have to [solve all](http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/) the `position:fixed` headaches in mobile browsers?

I have a Desktop App (twitter bootstrap based) that has postion:fixed toolbars that do not work well on mobile browsers?
I would like to incorporate the specifix fix without all the other functionality and CSS jQuery Mobile ships with.

Comment: I think they just added `position:fixed` to the supporting devices and just polyfilled everything else, but don't quote me on that. Was playing around with that new feature earlier and thats all it seemed to be. [link to polyfill for devices that don't support position:fixed](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-FixedToolbar-Legacy-Polyfill)

Comment: Yes i have seen this polyfill too. But this polyfill requires me to include `jquery.mobile.css` and `jquery.mobile.js`. I would like to go without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy (more or less):

1) Browser sniffing to generate a blacklist.
2) Position:fixed for supporting browsers
3) Position:static for the rest

Inside JQM look for this section:

$.widget( "mobile.fixedtoolbar", $.mobile.widget, {...}

As a lot of mobile browsers do not supported pos:fix as of now, you will end up with static toolbars sitting at the bottom of your content in a lot of browsers!!!

There also is a [polyfill](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-FixedToolbar-Legacy-Polyfill) to get back the previous behavior (hide-reposition-show).

I'm just using a part of this polyfill to reposition elements before showing them like so:

```
 el.jqmData("fixed") == "top" ? el.css( "top", $( window ).scrollTop() + "px" ) :
    el.css( "bottom", wrap.outerHeight() - $( window ).scrollTop() - $.mobile.getScreenHeight() + "px" );
```

This works nicely, if your toolbars/elements do not have to be visible, because it calculates from a set position (scroll-stop-recalcualte) vs the original fixed toolbars (pre JQM 1.1) recalcualting **during scroll** (scroll-calculate-scroll-calculate), which is just too much of a strain on device hardware and caused the toolbars to stick or jump.

Comment: Yes, i think using only the parts of the polyfill without jqueryMobile dependancies goes in the right direction, and is what i am looking for. Do you know of any Demo where this method is implemented?

Ive also looked at the `$.widget( "mobile.fixedtoolbar", $.mobile.widget, {...}` inside JQM. But i dont know yet how to rewrite this function so it can be used in non JQM projects.

Comment: Hm. No demo I know of. The old version was easy to plug out (just declare your element - like my "el" in above snippet) instead of JQM toolbarselector. The new version must work the same, so there should be a toolbar-alike-selector, which denotes the elements that should be fixed. Replace these elements with the elements of your choosing and pull out the widget. Then just see if there are any other functions used from JQM ($.mobile.getScreenHeight() I assume) and pull these out aswell